# DBA practice on cloud

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I'm a PL/SQL developer, but since I'm about to start a DBA junior course and I'd like to have a test workspace for testing (manage tablespace, create user, REDO management, Backup and Recovery with RMAN, ...) have you got any free way on cloud to advise me for DBA trial? I've found this link https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/ but before registering, I'd like to know if someone here has already registered and tell me if it's possible to practice as DBA

Thanks in advance

Mark

Comment: If you have a machine of your own consider installing docker on it and downloading [one of the official Oracle images](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images). If you're just starting out having a database on an environment under your control is better than the cloud.

Comment: An alternative to docker would be to install Oracle Virtual Box on our own PC. Use that to create a VM running Oracle Linux, and install Oracle on that.  All for free, and you'll learn a lot of ancillary stuff - os and networking - that will serve you well as a DBA.  I've never used docker, so can't speak to a comparison between the two.

Comment: The database available by default in the free tier of the cloud has different characteristics than a locally installed database. I think @EdStevens suggestion is the best, unless you are already familiar with Docker.